# How to script SFTP two-factor authentication?

Tags: automation, authentication, sftp

I need to script file transfers between two servers. Local server is RHEL 5.x. Remote location uses two-factor authentication (key+password). Authenticates fine on the key-pair but I can't find syntax that would allow me to relay the password.

Command example that partialy works:

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=<path_to_ssh_key> <un>@<site>
```

SCP is apparently a possibility, but the remote location apparently doesn't have anyone who uses it so future support might be shallow.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you looked into [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) before?  You can basically set it up to watch for a specific return, and then send the password. Since it integrates well into scripts, you could store the password in an encrypted file and decrypt only when needed (using GPG)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but as you talk about scripting, the answer might be to use `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p "Password" sftp -oIdentityFile="path_to_ssh_key" uname@site.ext
```